# Comparision of String to a CString in the Swift does not work

Tags: ios, string, swift, equals, c-strings

I'm trying to check if column exists or not in the sqlite db using swift.
The "MyTable" has 3 columns "Name","Age","Class". I need to check if column "Service" exists or not. Below is code to do so :

```
    var columnExists = 0
    var db: COpaquePointer = nil
    var output_stmt: COpaquePointer = nil
    var columnExists = 0

    if sqlite3_open(databasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "pragma table_info ('MyTable')", -1, &output_stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(output_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                let address = sqlite3_column_text(output_stmt, 1)
                columnName = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(address))!


                if(columnName == "Service") {
                    columnExists = 1
                    break;
                }
            }
     }
     else
     {
        columnExists = 0
     }
```

Even after adding new column "Service" to "MyTable",
the above code,if(columnName == "Service") does not hit at all and not sure what could be reason that columnName equals Service does not work. How do i achieve this

Comment: You said that your table has the three columns "Name","Age","Class", so a column "Service" does not exist ...

Comment: Your first step in tackling this problem should have either been setting a breakpoint on the comparison that's not working and inspect the value of `columnName` at that point, or simply log `columnName` right before that `if` statement.  And then you would have seen `columnName` never has a value of `"Service"`, so your code is doing what it is supposed to do (except that `columnExists` should probably be a `Bool` and the `else` is probably wholly unnecessary).

Comment: @cybergeeeek this `columnExists` `Int` is a huge code smell...

Comment: @AMomchilov - updated the code, forgot to add columnExists variable.

Comment: @cybergeeeek My comment wasn't directly pertaining to your questio. you're using `columnExists` as `Int`, where a `bool` belongs. Either way, using a flag like that is a code smell, likely indicates poor design that could be reworked to be better